# Finding the index of a sublist in a Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am struggling with finding the index of a sublist in a Numpy Array.

```
a = [[False,  True,  True,  True],
     [ True,  True,  True,  True],
     [ True,  True,  True,  True]]
sub = [True, True, True, True]
index = np.where(a.tolist() == sub)[0]
print(index)
```

This code gives me

```
array([0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2])
```

which I cannot explain to me. Shouldn't the output be `array([1, 2])` and why is it not? Also how can I achieve this output?

Comment: Your code gives me the array `[0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]`, not `[]`.

Comment: @timgeb you're right. I updated this

Comment: actually the definition of `a` is also incorrect, bacause it's meant to be a shaped np array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, here's my idea:

```
>>> a
array([[False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
>>> sub
>>> array([ True,  True,  True,  True])
>>> 
>>> result, = np.where(np.all(a == sub, axis=1))
>>> result
array([1, 2])
```

*Details regarding this solution:*

`a == sub` gives you

```
>>> a == sub
array([[False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

a boolean array where for each row the `True`/`False` value indicates if the value in `a` is equal to the corresponding value in `sub`. (`sub` is being *broadcasted* along the rows here.)

`np.all(a == sub, axis=1)` gives you

```
>>> np.all(a == sub, axis=1)
array([False,  True,  True])
```

a boolean array corresponding to the rows of `a` that are equal to `sub`.

Using `np.where` on this sub-result gives you the indices where this boolean array is `True`.

*Details regarding your attempt:*

`np.where(a == sub)` (the `tolist` is unnecessary) gives you two arrays which together indicate the indices where the array `a == sub` is `True`.

```
>>> np.where(a == sub)
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

If you would zip these two arrays together you would get the row/column indices where `a == sub` is `True`, i.e.

```
>>> for row, col in zip(*np.where(a==sub)):
...:    print('a == sub is True at ({}, {})'.format(row, col))
a == sub is True at (0, 1)
a == sub is True at (0, 2)
a == sub is True at (0, 3)
a == sub is True at (1, 0)
a == sub is True at (1, 1)
a == sub is True at (1, 2)
a == sub is True at (1, 3)
a == sub is True at (2, 0)
a == sub is True at (2, 1)
a == sub is True at (2, 2)
a == sub is True at (2, 3)
```

Comment: Very helpful for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that without using numpy only with native python

`res = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if all(e==f for e, f in zip(v, sub))]`